# Press button from apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, approval-process, button, popup

what i'm trying to manage, is have trigger that will execute submit for approval button.

So far i made a trigger that automatically submits record for approval, based on fields value, but what I really need is possibility to cancel this submission.

So in short, i need to be able to automatically submit record for approval, but with the popup window that normally works with the manual press of the button.
(there is no popup with my trigger)

Any ideas how this could be made?

Here's the trigger

```
trigger OppSubmitForApprovalHigh on Opportunity (after update, before insert) {
List<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest> approvalReqList=new List<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest>();

for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {
    // Iterate over each sObject
}

Opportunity opp = [SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity
WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new];


    for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++) {



    string currentAccountID = opp.AccountId;

    system.debug('AccountID'+ currentAccountID);

    string accountDiscount = 'Select Available_Discount__c from Account where Id = \'' + currentAccountID +'\'';
    Account accDiscount = Database.query(accountDiscount);




  if (Trigger.new[i].Opportunity_Discount__c > accDiscount.Available_Discount__c)
 {           
 // create the new approval request to submit    
   Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();   
   req.setComments('Submitted for approval. Please approve.');
   req.setObjectId(opp.Id);
   approvalReqList.add(req);        
   }   
}
// submit the approval request for processing        
List<Approval.ProcessResult> resultList = Approval.process(approvalReqList);        
// display if the reqeust was successful
for(Approval.ProcessResult result: resultList )
{        
System.debug('Submitted for approval successfully: '+result.isSuccess());      
}

}
```

Comment: Is it a vf page? can you post your trigger code and vf page?

Comment: It's just a standard opportunity record page.

Comment: Popup from a trigger? That doesn't even make sense. What would that mean in the context of data loader, or any other API for that matter?

Comment: Probably you are looking for a flag which if false do not submit for approval and submit otherwise.If yes you can achieve this from a custom setting field.

Comment: Adrian Larson - i'm not sure if thiscan be called a popup, i just need the window that, checks if ur sure about sending record to approval.

Comment: You are better off with an image formula field that tells the user that the record is "ready for submission for approval" and tells the user to click the Submit for Approval button

Comment: Thing is that i know there are some workarounds, but this is what my boss wants me to do,  it's nothing urgent but it would be nice to have.

Comment: The fundamental incompatibility is that you are trying to inject a UI element into an architecture that does not guarantee the presence of a UI in the first place.

Comment: It looks like you need to create a custom button that redirects to a VF page instead of a standard "Save" and there check your logic and show a message asking for confirmation if needed. Or probably onclick JS button might work.

Comment: You got me wrong Adrian, i dont want to add custom popup(UI element) to the trigger, i want to execute "Submit for approval" button as if it was normaly clicked, because it guarantees me that window associated with it will appear. I understand that this is silly way of doing approval overall, but this is what was requested and i'm just trying to find a way to accomplish this.

Comment: I need this functionality mostly because, users that entered too big discount value, should be able to decide if they want to cancel submission, but normally record will automatically be sent to approval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Put a soft alert on the page using a conditional image formula

  ```
   IF (NOT(IsApproved__c) && HasDiscountExceedingGuidelines__c ,
       IMAGE("/img/samples/flag_red.gif" , 'Red' ,12,12) & 
            ' Discount exceeds guidelines. Override using checkbox' & BR(),
       NULL)
  ```
- Add a checkbox `OverrideDiscountWarning__c`
- Alter the trigger to automatically submit the approval process when:

  - `HasDiscountExceedingGuidelines__c` is false or
  - `HasDiscountExceedingGuidelines__c` is true and `OverrideDiscountWarning__c` is true

Be sure, of course, that once approval process is in flight/finished-approved, that each further update of the object doesn't automatically re-invoke the approval submission logic.

You have to push the conditional approval to fields on the page that will be transmitted as part of the trigger context (as well as using fields to tell the user that some override action is required).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this should be just what i needed. Would adding (NOT(IsApproved__c) to trigger rules (on approval execution) make sure that future updates doesn't re-invoke approval process?

Comment: @LinQ -- yes, that sounds like a good idea. The answer I gave is a framework for you to adapt - but I think you get the idea